# The notion of abelian covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I have some doubts about what an abelian covering is, and I'll try my best to articulate them.

In Serre's *Algebraic groups and class fields* Chapter VI.2, he fixed a base field $k$ with algebraic closure $\bar{k}$, and $V$ a normal irreducible algebraic variety over $\bar{k}$ with function field $K = \bar{k}(V)$. For a finite separable extension $L/K$, the *normalization* $W$ of $V$ in $L$ is the variety whose local rings are obtained by decomposing the integral closure in $L$ of the local rings $\mathcal{O}_P$ of points $P \in V$. The variety $W$ thus defined comes with a projection $\pi: W \rightarrow V$ and we say that the covering $\pi$ is *abelian* if the field extension $L/K$ is.

Now let $G$ be a finite abelian etale group scheme over $k$. Then the classes of $G$-torsors $Y \rightarrow V$ over $V$ are elements of the etale cohomology group $H^1(V,G)$. So an element $[Y] \in H^1(V,G)$ is such that we have $Y \times G \cong Y \times Y$.

I know that the $G$-torsors $Y$ are called *abelian coverings* of $V$, but is it in the same sense as the one given by Serre? In other words, is $Y$ the normalization of $V$ in some finite extension $L$ of $\bar{k}(V)$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(L/K) \cong G$? Also, how do we check if a $G$-torsor is unramified, are there convenient results?

Any references or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $k$ plays no role here. It would clarify things to forget about $\overline{k}$ assume $k$ algebraically closed. I point this out because if $V$ is a *$k$-variety* and $f:W\to V$ is a $G$-torsor, we can conclude that $f$ is an abelian covering only if $W$ is irreducible *and $G$ is constant*, the latter condition being of course satisfied over $\overline{k}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(1) $G$-torsors are always unramified, because they are étale-locally trivial, and unramifiedness may be checked etale-locally.

(2) A $G$-torsor is a $G$-covering in the sense of Serre as long as it is irreducible. We simply take $L$ to be the function field $\overline{k}(Y)$. Since the morphism $Y \to V$ is finite, $Y \times_V \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_P \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_P$ is finite, so every function on $Y \times_V\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_P$ is integral over $\mathcal O_P$, and because $V$ is normal and $Y \to V$ is etale, $Y$ is normal, so every element of $L$ integral over $\mathcal O_P$ is a function in $Y \times_V\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_P$.

Thus the ring of functions on $Y \times_V\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_P$ is the integral closure, which decomposes into local rings corresponding to the fibers, as desired.

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to be certain of what "etale-locally trivial" means. For a $G$-torsor $Y \rightarrow V$, if $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of $Y$ under the etale topology, then $U_i \rightarrow V$ is the identity map for each $i$, is this right?

Comment: @KelvinLian No. What it means is there exists an etale cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $Y \times_V U_i = G \times U_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Oh I see, ok thank you.