# Cohomology map induced by inclusion of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, etale-cohomology

Let $C$ be a smooth affine geometrically integral curve of genus $\geq 1$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $\iota: C \rightarrow C'$ denote the inclusion into its smooth compactification. We note that the set $C' \backslash C$ is finite.

For a finite abelian etale group scheme $G$, let $H^1(X,G)$ (etale cohomology) parameterize all classes of $G$-torsors over $X$, i.e., unramified abelian coverings according to the answer in my [previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426585/the-notion-of-abelian-covers). Now we have the induced map of coverings $$\iota^*: H^1(C',G) \rightarrow H^1(C,G),$$ which is clearly given by pull-backs via $\iota$. I have some questions about this map:

**Question 1.**   How does one explicitly show that the pull-back of a covering $Y \rightarrow C'$ under $G$ actually still gives us a $G$-torsor?

I know this is supposed to be well-known but I couldn't find a specific reference for it. I tried to show that $$(Y \times _{C'} C) \times_k G \cong (Y \times _{C'} C) \times_k (Y \times_{C'} C)$$ using the fact that we have an isomorphism $Y \times _k G \cong Y \times _k Y$ but to no avail.

**Question 2.** Can one explicitly construct an example where this map **fails** to be an isomorphism?

An example of an isomorphism will be to let $k = \mathbb{C}$, $C'$ an elliptic curve (2-torus in this case), and $C$ one point removed (once-punctured torus).

Gladly appreciate any references towards better understanding this induced map of coverings.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $Y\times_kG \cong Y\times_{C’}Y$ instead of $Y\times_kG\cong Y\times_k Y$? In the latter it seems, for example, like the dimensions wouldn’t match, but the former essentially says that “the pullback of a principal bundle to itself trivializes.” And it looks like it would fix your approach to restricting to $C$.

Comment: @john By principal bundle, I'm guessing you mean the torsor that *looks very much like* $G$, i.e., the trivial torsor?

Comment: I just used “principal bundle” as a synonym of “$G$-torsor” here, more to indicate where the intuition behind my suggestion came from than anything else.

Comment: @john Actually, I think I need to say that $G$ is a group scheme defined over $C'$, and then the correct way of writing should be $Y \times_{C'} G \cong Y \times _{C'} Y$, do you think this is correct?

Comment: @john I'm just following the construction of Chapter III.4 in Milne's Etale Cohomology.

Comment: Suppose $G=\mu_n$, where $n$ is prime to the characteristic of $k$. Let $C=G_m$. Then $C'={\bf P}^1_k$. In that case $H^1(C',G)=0$ and $H^1(C,G)={\bf Z}/(n{\bf Z})$ so the groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: (here $G_m={\rm Spec}(k[x]_x)$ is the one-dimensional torus)

Comment: @DamianRössler How did you compute that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1_k, \mu_n) = 0$?

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$ the étale cohomology group coincides with the usual cohomology group (for the analytic topology), right ? In that case, If $C$ is a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb C$ with at least two points removed, then the map $H^1(C',G) \to H^1(C,G)$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: @NicolasTholozan I knew it had something to do with removing at least 2 points, but I couldn't make it explicit, i.e., construct a $G$-cover on $C$ that isn't defined by pull-back.

Comment: @Kelvin Lian. For any scheme $S$ the exact sequence of group schemes $0\to \mu_{n,S}\to G_{m,S}\stackrel{{\rm mult}\, n}{\to}G_{m,S}\to 0$ gives rise to an exact sequence $$0\to \mu_n(S)\to G_m(S)\to G_m(S)\to H^1(S,\mu_n)\to{\rm Pic}(S)\stackrel{{\rm mult}\,n}{\to}{\rm Pic}(S).$$ If $S={\bf P}^1_k$ then $G_m(S)=k^*$ and ${\rm Pic}(S)={\bf Z}$. This gives $H^1(S,\mu_n)=0$ (since $k$ is alg. closed). If $S=G_m$, then it gives $H^1(S,\mu_n)=({\bf Z}\oplus k^*)/n({\bf Z}\oplus k^*)={\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$, since ${\rm Pic}(G_m)=0$.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you that was very helpful. I suppose $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{G}_m)$ is simply the set of homomorphisms $\mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$, which can be given by $x \mapsto \alpha x$ for $\alpha \in k^*$ or $x \mapsto x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, hence the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus k^*$.

Comment: Yes. Directly from the def. we have $G_m(G_m)=H^0(G_m,{\cal O}^*_{G_m})=$units in $k(x]_x$ and the units of $k[x]_x$ are of the form $ax^i$ where $i\in{\bf Z}$ and $a\in k^*$.